# An internship in synthesis, is it good for academic career?

Tags: career-path

I am a chemistry student on my first year of master's, my love is purely towards making novel protein inhibitors, mostly for cancer research. I can do the synthesis and I am getting better at molecular dynamics. I want to pursue a PhD in that field, but mainly synthesis.

At some point in time, I applied for an internship, not thinking too much, now it turns out I got it and don't know what to do. It is an internship in pure organic synthesis. It is a company with high reputation, a contractor for synthesising building blocks for medicinal chemistry. While I suppose it could look good for a potential future employer, the reviews on Glassdoor are awful, stating that the management is terrible, the work is stressful with many people leaving. Additionally I would have to travel abroad for 6 months and I am not sure if the pay would be enough.

Would you take the internship if you were me? I would want to pursue PhD at my university afterwards and I don't know if such internship could help me get the PhD or some kind of grant afterwards. Would this kind of internship mean something to a supervisor in academia? Is it worth it?

Comment: ‘… and I am not sure if the pay would be enough.’ What did you find out when you followed through on questions to the company’s HR? It’ll often have a pretty good idea about salary and local cost of living.

Comment: @Aruralreader Honestly, they aren't especially helpful, the HR is the COO, when I asked him if the pay would be sufficient, he just cut me off saying it will be enough. It's Switzerland, so the company is deducting lots of different taxes from the salary, I am still awaiting response what the net salary will be. The contract doesn't even tell me that.

Answer (score 1):

Internships are definitely a plus on an academic CV, especially if they give you skills related to your academic career, even better if you get publications from them. An internship in a research lab is probably slightly more valuable, but one in a company will also teach you a lot and be useful if you ever go back to industry.

Here, I’d recommend the following:

1. See if you can connect to current or past employees of the company and get more insights about the work environment and the cost of life (as suggested in comments). Linkedin might be helpful for that.
2. At the same time, look for other internships, lab tech, lab manager opportunities, ideally in labs where you might want to do your PhD later. These are probably the most useful to help you get a PhD position (at least in the US).

Finally: if you have a choice between the company or a research lab internship, choose the research lab; if the company does seem toxic, do not go there; if it doesn’t seem toxic, and you have no better alternative, I’d say go with it!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, qualified with my background as chemistry faculty at a large R1 institution, with significant experience on graduate admissions.

Will it help you get into a PhD program? Potentially. The strongest indicators of success for a PhD student is publications, conference presentations, and grades (you need a minimum to be considered and ranked, and they tell us if you will be able to pass entrance exams, core classes, and candidacy requirements or otherwise you will not be able to start your research). Strong letters of support from reputable faculty in a position to make an assessment of your potential to earn a PhD are important. If everything else is strong, then industry experience (especially if in R&D) will be valuable - even better if you get a letter of reference from a supervisory R&D Scientist, and even better if they are a well-regarded and well-published research fellow. Experience as just a low-level technician running repetitive and routine samples or analysis for production will not be helpful. If that is the case, you are much better off joining an active research group in your department to gain more experience.

Additionally, you may consider funded opportunities to gain research experience in an academic lab abroad.

Will it help you get future grants? No, not really. As a chemist your #1 commodity is peer reviewed publications in well-respected journals. That's what you trade in, that's what you get ranked on (in addition to quality of institution and rigor and reputation of your advisors).

So why would you take this internship? If it is a strong R&D department that is very active, then see above for the rationale. Otherwise, only do this if you intend to go into a low-level industry position after PhD. Invariably, if you want to go into high level R&D, they will be more receptive to a strong publication record, and most likely a strong Postdoctoral placement with faculty that has a history of placing people in said company/industry (sounds like for you that would be pharma or fine chemicals).

Good luck with your decision. External and international experiences can be incredibly valuable, but you must make sure they align with your goals.